# CodeIgniter installation now returns a blank screen

Tags: codeigniter

Using XAMPP for running codeigniter getting blank screen everytime in localhost. Other codeigniter project working well

```
$db['default']['username'] = "";
$db['default']['password'] = "";
$db['default']['database'] = "";

// The following values can probably stay the same.
$db['default']['hostname'] = "";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";

$active_group = "default";
$active_record = TRUE;
```

Comment: Check the error logs to see the errors causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

A blank screen usually means you have missed a " ; " someplace. I would say check your syntax completely. The missing ; might be in your view, controller or in the model. Almost any syntax error can bring you a blank screen

Comment: The same code runs well in one of friends computer and iam using those files. @Brad

Comment: The same code runs well in one of friends computer and iam using those files.

Comment: There is obviously a difference between your code and the friends code. Check your syntax.

Comment: Yes I am getting that impression. As I said, there are all kinds of things you need to check. Is your base url right, is your config and database settings right? Are you checking your logs in the application logs folder? That alone should tell you whats wrong